# How to rewrite specific urls in lighttpd

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I moved a wiki install on lighttpd from https://www.example.com/wiki to a subdomain of https://wiki.example.com so I need to redirect anything wiki related to the new subdomain.

url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/wiki" => "https://wiki.example.com",

)

This gives me an error 404 not found as the browser is still pointed to the old page.

In addition I would like to add a rule to handle pages people already have bookmarked such as sending

https://www.example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

to 
https://wiki.example.com/index.php?title=Main_Page

I ended up doing this:

```
url.redirect = ( "^/wiki/(.*)$ => https://wiki.example.net/$1",
"^/wiki/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?" => "https://wiki.example.net/index.php?title=$1&$2",
)
```

This works on 99% of the site. However there are a few forums threads that do not display correctly now because they are trying to redirect.

This one works and can view the forum normally

```
https://www.example.net/forums/showthread.php?796166-Wiki-Skins
```

This one breaks and tries to redirect

```
https://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?796105-Wiki-Extensions-amp-Gadgets
```

Comment: First url.redirect match wins, so that second rule (in your edit) will never execute.  Flip the order of those rules to put the more specialized match first and the more general match second.

Answer (score 0):

While Stackoverflow is a good resource, please also try reading the primary source documentation for the tool you are asking about.  In this case, that is lighttpd documentation.

You might consider using mod_redirect to redirect the client.  See documentation and examples at https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRedirect

Comment: I ended up doing this but someurl.redirect = ( "^/wiki/(.*)$ => https://wiki.twcenter.net/$1",
"^/wiki/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?" => "https://wiki.twcenter.net/index.php?title=$1&$2",
)thing still is not right.